# There are $5$ boxes numbered from $1$ to $5$. There is $1$ Red and $2k$ black balls in the $k^{th}$ box

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $5$ boxes numbered from $1$ to $5$. There is $1$ Red and $2k$ black balls in the $k^{th}$ box,
$k=1,2,3,4,5$ .From each box either one red ball is taken or one or more than one black
balls are taken. But from each box both coloured balls are never taken (ball of same
colours are all alike).

Now which of the following holds good?

(A) Total number of ways selecting odd number of red balls is $4725$

(B) Total number of ways of selecting even number of red balls is $5670$.

(C) Total number of ways selecting odd number of red balls is $5670$

(D) Total number of ways of selecting even number of red balls is $4725$

**I cannot think of how to proceed this problem**

Comment: @N.F.Taussig So, number of ways to select one red ball from box $1$ is $3$, number of ways of selecting $1$ red ball from box $2$ is $5$, and number of ways of selecting red ball from box $3$  is $7$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig My first Doubt is since the all black balls are identical so number of ways of selecting one Black ball is $1$ and number of ways of selecting 3 black balls is also $1$, isn't it?

(2) Why you are selecting only odd number of black balls. Question is asking odd number of red balls only.

Comment: I misread the question.  For the number of ways of selecting an odd number of red balls, consider the possibilities that one, three, or five red balls are selected.  For the number of ways of selecting an even number of red balls, consider the possibilities that zero, two, or four red balls are selected.  For boxes from which black balls are taken, what matters is how many black balls are taken.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I am still not getting this question. Here is what i did number of ways of selecting one red ball, First I selected one box in $5 \choose 1$ ways and the multiplied by $1$ because number of ways of selecting one Red ball is $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Strategy:**

1. Selecting an odd number of red balls:  This means you select the only red ball from one, three, or five of the boxes.  From the other boxes, you select from up to $2k$ black balls, but you must choose at least one.
2. Selecting an even number of red balls:  This means you select the only red ball from zero, two, or four of the boxes.  From the other boxes, you select from up to $2k$ black balls, but you must choose at least one.

To illustrate with a particular case.  Suppose we select red balls from the first three boxes.  There is one possible selection from the first box (the red ball), one possible selection from the second box (the red ball), one possible selection from the third box (the red ball), eight possible selections from the fourth box (since we can choose $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,$ or $8$ black balls), and $10$ selections from the fifth box (since we can choose $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,$ or $10$) of the black balls.  Therefore, this case corresponds to $1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 8 \cdot 10 = 80$ possible choices.

Notice that there are $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways to select from which three of the five boxes you will select a red ball.  In each case, the number of black balls you can choose depends on which boxes remain.  We considered one of these $10$ cases above.

There are $\binom{5}{j}$ cases to consider when you select exactly $j$ red balls.

Can you proceed?

Comment: Thanks, I obtained the answer $(1)$ When one red ball is selected then number of ways $4384 \;$. $(2)$ When three red balls are selected then number of ways are $340\; \;$. $(3)$ When 5 red balls are selected then number of way is $1$ . So total number of ways when odd number of red balls are selected is $4384+340+1=4725\;\;$. **I would like to know any short method to solve this problem because this involve too much of case work**

Answer (score -1):

Let $X$ the no. Of selection of even red balls
$Y$ be the selection of odd no. Of red balls

By inclusion exclusion
$X - Y =(2-1)(4-1)(6-1)(8-1)(10-1)$
And
$X + Y = (2+1)(4+1)(6+1)(8+1)(10+1)$
Solving we get
$X= 5670$
$Y= 4725$

Comment: Could you please explain how the inclusion-exclusion principle works here?